# X forwarding the other way around cross platforms?

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding, xming, xforwarding

Ok, so we've had X forwarding for quite some time. And it's a nice feature where you want to have some remote applications running remotely and the ui drawn locally.

And I noticed that it's possible to also do this from windows, where you can install xming and run linux application remotely and display them as local.

However does anyone know if it's possible to do this the other way around. i.e let xming handle windows applications and forward them to a linux machine so they can be drawn locally?

Cheers Kim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot do this.  The X server software is designed to receive a forwarded display, not send one.  Not that it could, as the underlying display protocols in Windows are completely different.

However, forwarding a single Windows window can be accomplished with [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com).  I have used TeamViewer in this manner, so I know it works.

Some other possible solutions I have not used might work for you.  Some VNC servers, like [TightVNC](https://www.tightvnc.com/), have a single window sharing feature.  There are other programs, such as [xpra](http://xpra.org/) and [WinSwitch](http://winswitch.org/), that can do this as well.

On a side note, you can forward the display from Windows Subsystem for Linux distros to other display servers, as well as from the [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) X server.  However, those applications being run arent Windows native programs, so I doubt they meet your requirements.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case.. :) Thank you!